# VS Code - how to document an object using JSDoc

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc

I have a variable *storage*, that stores all elements of type *Person*. So basically it is a dictionary with key *URL* and value *PersonInstance*:

```javascript
let storage = {}
storage["localhost.com/person/1"] = new Person("John Wick");
```

Actually I could do it by writing:

```
/** 
 * @type {Object.<string, Person>}
 */
```

But VS Code Intellisense does not work in such case. Is there other way to document such object with unlimited number of keys in VS Code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VScode's javascript intellisense is powered by TypeScript which unfortunatly does not currently support the `Object.<string, Person>` type syntax. [Here's the bug tracking this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15105).

You can work around this by using typescript syntax for the map:

```
/**
 * @type {{ [key: string]: Person }}
 */
const storage = {}
```

which will improve the intellisense in vscode but is not a standard or widely supported jsdoc type.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Missing support for `Object<string, T>` has been added. However, be aware that casing matters!

**Works**

`Object<string, T>` where string is the index and T is the value type.

**Does NOT work**

`object<string, T>` - object MUST start with upper case: Object

`Object<String, T>` - String MUST be all lower case: string

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is better to use `Map` instead of object. So basically you can write something like this

```
    /**
     * @type {Map<string, Person>}
     */
    let bsStorage = new Map();
```

NOTE: And if you concern about older browsers, that do not support ES6, you can transpile using Babel.